Всегда ли вводные слова не отделяются от сочинительных союзов в начале предложения?

Есть правило ПАС §95
Вводные слова и сочетания слов, находясь рядом с сочинительными 
союзами, отделяются или не отделяются от них запятыми в зависимости от 
контекста.

Не отделяются запятой вводные слова от союзов, стоящих в начале 
предложения: И действительно, он скоро уехал; А между прочим, магазин 
уже был закрыт; И в самом деле, послышались голоса внизу (Ч.); И 
пожалуй, он правильно поступил.


Примеры приведены для союза И, а где же примеры для других союзов, в частности  для союза ИЛИ?


Нацкорпус
Или, может быть: Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013).  Или, быть может, я действительно сошел с ума?
Или, быть может: Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977). Или, может быть, ты себя считаешь немцем?
И, по-видимому: Л. А. Данилкин. Ленин: Пантократор солнечных пылинок (2017).  И, по-видимому, полагал Троцкий, Сталин, который в самом деле отравил Ленина в Горках — руками Генриха Ягоды, нарочно распространял эту версию, чтобы подготовить себе алиби.

Так как правильно? Насколько корректно такое обобщение для присоединительных союзов?

